# Delete duplicate rows based on time (minute or hour) DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have an issue that I can't resolve after some research.

Here my situation :

[image: Situation example]

I want to delete duplicate data based on time in the same hour. For example, for the ID "5267", I want to remove the row 03/02/2021 08:22:00 and keep the two others row that on different date and time ( 5267 - 29/01/2021 07:50:28 and 5267 - 03/02/2021 08:21:57).

I don't know if my example is clear. If you have question ask me.

Thank you for your future answer

Great Day

Comment: what if there more than 2 rows for a same hour? you wants to keep first/last record of each our hour? need to define the logic first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
delete from tbl 
where rowid not in (select min(rowid) 
                    from tbl 
                     group by id, cnt,to_char(dt,'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')
                   );
```

Here is [db fiddle file](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=768c2c5de9db31f21b0d610e15627cd8)

Comment: Thank you for your time, 

Can you explain me where the "rowid" come from ? is it an Oracle's syntax ? If yes what is the equivalence in Sql server ?

If you have the explanation in DAX i take it too

Thanks

Comment: @Beelnutso Yes my code is for Oracle. Actually in MS SQL doesn't have "rowid", but you can create it as bellow:

`select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS Row#, dt, id, cnt 
from tbl;`

I am sorry, I don't have the explanation for DAX :(